# In SwipeMenuListView custom row layout Textview is visible only first position when SwipeMenu is open

Tags: android, custom-adapter

When i swipe SwipeMenuListview item it shows only first position's textview but i want when i swipe list item it shows all position textview's text.
For Example, in my case i want 4 textview visible when i swipe on list item.

---

[image: My requirement is when i swipe list item then all Songs size is display in textview.]

[image: Currently when i swipe list item it shows only first position's song size.]

### MainActivity.java

```
public class ProfilePersonalDownloadActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    ProfilePersonalDownloadAdapter profilePersonalDownloadAdapter;

    @BindView(R.id.lvProfileSongDownloadList)
    SwipeMenuListView lvProfileSongDlList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_personal_download);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        profilePersonalDownloadAdapter = new ProfilePersonalDownloadAdapter(ProfilePersonalDownloadActivity.this);
        lvProfileSongDlList.setAdapter(profilePersonalDownloadAdapter);

        int t_Session = 0;
        for (int i = 0, len = profilePersonalDownloadAdapter.getCount(); i < len; i++) { // detailMovieAdapter.getCount()返回数据项的数目
            View listItem = profilePersonalDownloadAdapter.getView(i, null, lvProfileSongDlList);
            listItem.measure(0, 0); // 计算子项View 的宽高
            t_Session += listItem.getMeasuredHeight(); // 统计所有子项的总高度
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params1 = lvProfileSongDlList.getLayoutParams();
        params1.height = t_Session + (lvProfileSongDlList.getDividerHeight() * (profilePersonalDownloadAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        lvProfileSongDlList.setLayoutParams(params1);

        SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {

            @Override
            public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
                // create "delete" item
                SwipeMenuItem deleteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                        getApplicationContext());
                // set item background
                deleteItem.setBackground(R.color.view_color);
                // set item width
                deleteItem.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                // set a icon
                deleteItem.setTitle("Delete");

                deleteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dltrash);
                // add to menu
                menu.addMenuItem(deleteItem);
            }
        };
        lvProfileSongDlList.setMenuCreator(creator);
        // step 2. listener item click event
        lvProfileSongDlList.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
//                ApplicationInfo item = mAppList.get(position);
                switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                        // delete song                           
//                        lvProfileSongDlList.getChildAt(position);
                        Toast.makeText(ProfilePersonalDownloadActivity.this, "delete song called"/*+position*//*+" "+index*/, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        lvProfileSongDlList.removeViewAt(position);
                        profilePersonalDownloadAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        // set SwipeListener
        lvProfileSongDlList.setOnSwipeListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnSwipeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSwipeStart(int position) {
                // swipe start
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeEnd(int position) {
                // swipe end
            }
        });
        // set MenuStateChangeListener
        lvProfileSongDlList.setOnMenuStateChangeListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuOpen(int position) {
               for (int i=0;i<profilePersonalDownloadAdapter.getCount();i++){
                Log.d("TAG", "onSwipeStart: "+i);
                View v = lvProfileSongDlList.getChildAt(i).getRootView();
                if (v != null) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onMenuOpen: "+"inside if "+i);
                    TextView tvSongSize = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSongSize);
                    tvSongSize.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuClose(int position) {
                for (int i=0;i<profilePersonalDownloadAdapter.getCount();i++){
                Log.d("TAG", "onSwipeStart: "+i);
                View v = lvProfileSongDlList.getChildAt(i).getRootView();
                if (v != null) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onMenuOpen: "+"inside if "+i);
                    TextView tvSongSize = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSongSize);
                    tvSongSize.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
//                }
            }
        });
    }


    private int dp2px(int dp) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

---

### CustomAdapter

```
public class ProfilePersonalDownloadAdapter extends BaseSwipListAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mcontext;
    ViewHolder holder;

    class ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.tvSongSize)
        TextView tvSongSize;
////
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        }
    }

    public ProfilePersonalDownloadAdapter(/*ArrayList<AddJobModel> tempItemList, */Context context/*, boolean isEditClickedFromOptionMenu*/) {
        inflater = null;
//        productItemList = tempItemList;
        mcontext = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return (long) i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_profile_download_song_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

            convertView.setTag(this.holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        return convertView;
    }
}
```